# How to find fx and fy as functions if f(x, y) is given?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

While preparing for a mathematics exam, I am solving the following task.

> Find $f_x$ and $f_y$ as functions if $$f(x, y)=\frac{2y}{y+\cos x}$$

What I am currently performing is partial differentiation with regard to $x$ and $y$, and then integration of each of the derivatives, by leaving the constant of integration.

What is the general approach to solve tasks like this? Is that the correct approach, or would you suggest something better?

Comment: $f_x$ *is* the partial derivative with regard to $x$ of $f(x,y)$!

Comment: Thanks a lot @addy2012, somehow I missed that point.

Comment: No one's perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $f_x = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{(y+\cos x)\dfrac{\partial (2y)}{\partial x} - 2y\dfrac{\partial (y+\cos x)}{\partial x}}{(y+\cos x)^2}$

Comment: Thanks. I missed the fact that $f_x = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.